# Uninstall Octave

Tags: octave, uninstallation

I just compiled Octave source downloaded from the GNU site as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138832/how-to-install-the-latest-octave/221810#221810?newreg=cdc8aa5b629c4fdebdb24ed768af9e05). That is

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Is it possible to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the same directory where you ran `make install`, run `make uninstall`.

Both `install` and `uninstall` targets are targets mandated by [GNU standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html) and will work with any GNU project.  In addition, many programs using GNU autotools (all the ones where you run `./configure && make && make install`) will also have the `uninstall` target.